# Convert NURBS surface into Cubic Bezier Surface

Tags: algorithms, graphics, topology, digital-curve

The following post discussed how to convert(approximate) NURBS curve into cubic Bézier curve:
[Convert NURBS curve into Cubic Bezier Curve](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/102819/convert-nurbs-curve-into-cubic-bezier-curve)

I am trying to come up with an algorithm that converts(approximates) NURBS surface into cubic Bézier surfaces(patches), here is my thought(from the post):

1. convert NURBS to piecewise Rational B-Splines
2. convert B-spline to R-Bézier
3. Use progressive iterative approximation(PIA) to convert the Rational Bézier to Non-rational Bézier.

So far I have done the PIA algorithm, yet I don't know how to start the conversion from NURBS surfaces to R-Bézier surfaces, I know that the surface is of tensor product of two curves, but I have a hard time understanding how to use this property.

Comment: You are using an approximation anyway, so why converting to R-Bézier rather than using PIA directly ?

Comment: What points do I need from NURBS to give a good approximation?

Comment: More points where the curvature is high. Maybe *curve flattening* can be a good start.